# Why does texImage2D always give invalide operation error?

Tags: android, c, opengl-es

Here is my code, i can't found where does the problem hides.

```
bool setupGraphics(int w, int h) {
    printGLString("Version", GL_VERSION);
    printGLString("Vendor", GL_VENDOR);
    printGLString("Renderer", GL_RENDERER);
    printGLString("Extensions", GL_EXTENSIONS);

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    checkGlError("glViewport");

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    LOGI("setupGraphics(%d, %d)", w, h);
    gProgram = createProgram(gVertexShader, gFragmentShader);
    if (!gProgram) {
        LOGE("Could not create program.");
        return false;
    }
    gvPositionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "vPosition");
    checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation");

    //Init texture.
    makeCheckImage();  
    checkGlError("init texture1");
    glGenTextures(1, gTextureHandler);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, checkImage);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTextureHandler[0]);
    checkGlError("init texture2");

    gTextureUniformHandler = glGetUniformLocation(gProgram, "uTexture");
    gTextureCoordinateHandler = glGetAttribLocation(gProgram, "vTexCoordinate");
    checkGlError("init texture");

    return true;
}
```

And the logs:

```
I/libgl2jni(30066): GL Version = OpenGL ES 2.0 build 1.8.GOOGLENEXUS.ED945322@2112805
I/libgl2jni(30066): GL Vendor = Imagination Technologies
I/libgl2jni(30066): GL Renderer = PowerVR SGX 540
I/libgl2jni(30066): GL Extensions = GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_egl_sync GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_IMG_shader_binary GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc GL_IMG_texture_npot GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_program_binary GL_IMG_multisampled_render_to_texture
I/libgl2jni(30066): setupGraphics(480, 800)
I/libgl2jni(30066): after init texture2() glError (invalide operation)
```

if i Comment `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, checkImage);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTextureHandler[0]);` then everything goes fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself. The error is caused by the inconsistent parameter in `glTexImage2D`. If i change it to `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, checkImage);`, then error doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got the `glBindTexture` and the `glTexImage` in the wrong order. glTexImage updates the texture that's currently bound to the specified target.

Bind the texture first, then fill the data. Also you should bind the texture before setting the min/mag filters, as these also modify the bound texture.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. This is one of the errors i made. But after i move `glBindTexture` just below `glGenTexture`, the problem still exists.

Comment: I haven't add `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)', must i enable it? Becasue after i enable it in the beginning, it give a error in loading shader. BTW, the gl version i used is opengles2 and platform is android.

Comment: `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is not a valid command in OpenGLES2.0. It only applies to fixed pipeline opengl, which is removed from GLES2.0. I'd try adding some more error checks and find the exact line it's coming from. @user674199

Comment: I think i have added enough error checks in my code. The error comes from the exactly the line `glTexImage`.